Selenium+Python: XPath for attribute with special characters in the name
I have this line rendered on a web page:
<app-active-challenge-action-button-component [type]="$ctrl.ActiveChallengeActionButtonType.VOTE" [challenge]="$ctrl.challenge" _nghost-ng-c3021437172="" ng-version="17.0.8">...</app-active-challenge-action-button-component>

I'm trying to write a Selenium code in Python to click on that button. The unique identifier is [type]="$ctrl.ActiveChallengeActionButtonType.VOTE"
However, If I write this XPath:
//*[@[type]="$ctrl.ActiveChallengeActionButtonType.VOTE"]

Selenium complains that syntax is wrong (since I've used square brackets, a special character, in atribute name).
Adding back slashes in front of the square brackets does not work.
Omitting square brackets does not work either.
Is there a way to escape special characters in atribute names or some special way to specify an attribute that has special characters in its name?
Update. 2024-06-10
Looks like the website I'm dealing with is build on Angular.js and that needs a special library to deal with Angular specific code. PyTractor appears to have been a project to enable Angular app testing with Selenium for Python, but PyTractor has been dead for nearly a decade now.
